# Morley Triangle Proof

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

I am about to proof Morleys Triangle Theorem in a slightly different manner. I am only one step apart. I want to show, that

$$P_2C^\prime=P_2B^\prime$$

so that the triangle $P_2C^\prime B^\prime$ has the same angles at the side of the red one. For this I wanted to show that every corner is collinear with an edge of the red triangle and a point $P_i$. Any thoughts?

[image: Morley Triangle]

Comment: [John Conways's backwards proof](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Morley/conway.shtml) uses angles and similar triangles. Alternative proofs are linked further down that page.   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_trisector_theorem#Proofs) has a forwards  trigonometric proof using the triple angle formula

Comment: @Henry yes but I ask for a proof simply by comparing angles.

Comment: In what sense is Conway's proof not "comparing angles"?

Comment: @Henry I mean that I want to get that the angle is $\pi/3$ just by comparing them. He works backwards. I want a proof that continues mine.